# PyGtk3, How to prevent horizontal expand in VBox?

Tags: pygtk

i can prevent vertical expand in VBox with **pack_start(button, expand = False, fill = False, padding = 0)** command but widgets in VBox always expanding horizontally. i want make widget in center on horizontal plane. is there a method for make widget in center on horizontal plane ?

Comment: Please revise your question with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Craig, what are you saying Craig, i wrote everything for my problem please tell me what didn't you understand.

Comment: I suspect you are confusing expansion with centering. Widgets inside VBox are, by default, centered, which you can change with alignment methods. Same is true for widgets in Grids

Comment: `child.set_hexpand(False)`

Comment: @elya5, i tried, it doesn't work. i can solve my problem on glade. but i don't know a code for do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**set_halign()** method can do this

```
button = Gtk.Button()
button.set_halign(Gtk.Align.CENTER) # to center the widget
```

or

```
button = Gtk.Button(halign = Gtk.Align.CENTER)
```

Comment: Which was exactly what I commented 15 hours ago.

Comment: Use Gtk.Align.START to left-justify, and Gtk.Align.END to right-justify.